# How can I "ostensibly-but-not-really" break the one-definition-rule with enable_if and SFINAE?

Tags: c++11, sfinae, type-traits, enable-if

I want to define `template <typename T> struct is_non_negative` in one way for integral `T`'s and another way for floating-point `T`'s. Here's what I did:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_non_negative: public curry_right_hand_side<greater_equal<
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type>, constant<T, 0>> { };

template<typename T>
struct is_non_negative: public curry_right_hand_side<greater_equal<
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, T>::type>, constant_by_ratio<T, std::ratio<0,1>>> { };
```

This triggers a compiler error (GCC 4.9.3, `-std=c++11`):

```
error: class template "cuda::is_non_negative" has already been defined
```

and, well, it has, but it also hasn't, since the template instantiations are distinct.

How can I achieve this effect and actually get my code to compile?

Notes:

- Never mind how I defined `constant`, `constant_by_ratio` and `curry_right_hand_side` - they have been tested and work.
- If I replace the second `is_non_negative` with `foo` then this compiles and is usable - but not with the same identifier.
- The motivation for the two definitions here is the impossibility of using floating-point values as template parameters, but please don't focus on that aspect of the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could do something like this:

```
template<class T, class = void>
struct is_non_negative;

template<typename T>
struct is_non_negative<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>: public curry_right_hand_side<greater_equal<T>, constant<T, 0>> { };

template<typename T>
struct is_non_negative<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type>: public curry_right_hand_side<greater_equal<T>, constant_by_ratio<T, std::ratio<0,1>>> { };
```

Comment: after substitution you'll get `<T, T>`

Comment: This should probably do it, I guess.